# proof verification for truth table

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Hi I wanted to know if I got this question correct. Below is the question and the truth table. I said that they were not equivalent as columns 4 and 5 are different.

```
Using a truth table, decide whether or not the formulas (p∧q)⇒r and
p⇒(q ∨ r) are semantically equivalent. Explain how the truth table justifies
your answer

P   Q   R   ((P ∧ Q) → R)   (P → (Q ∨ R))
F   F   F     T               T
F   F   T     T               T
F   T   F     T               T
F   T   T     T               T
T   F   F     T               F
T   F   T     T               T
T   T   F     F               T
T   T   T     T               T
```

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: You could use a particular assignment: $P,Q$ true and $R$ false, makes the first one false, but the second one true, or use the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your truth table is [indeed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+%28%28P+AND+Q%29+IMPLIES+%28R%29%29) [correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+%28%28P%29+IMPLIES+%28R+OR+Q%29%29), to justify that $(p\land q)\to r$ and $p\to (q\lor r)$ aren't equivalent based on the truth table just use one counterexample. For instance, when $p$ is true and $q$ and $r$ are false then  $(p\land q)\to r$ will be true, however $p\to (q\lor r)$ will be false, hence they aren't equivalent.